# Overloading enum boolean comparison?

Tags: c++11, enums, overloading

I have a enum that I am trying to create operator overloads.   I am struggling with the boolean comparison operator.

Here is what I have:

```
enum class TraceLevel : uint32_t {

    // Basic logging levels (may be combined with trace level)
    All = 0xFFFFFFFF,
    None = 0x00000000,
    Info = 0x00000001,
    Warning = 0x00000002,
    Error = 0x00000004,
    Logging = 0x0000000F,
};

inline bool operator&&(TraceLevel __x, TraceLevel __y) {
    return static_cast<uint32_t>(__x & __y) > 0;
}

inline constexpr TraceLevel
operator&(TraceLevel __x, TraceLevel __y) {
    return static_cast<TraceLevel>
        (static_cast<uint32_t>(__x) & static_cast<uint32_t>(__y));
}
```

So with this enum class, I can issue the statements:

```
LogLevel a = LogLevel::Info;
LogLevel b = LogLevel::Warning;

LogLevel c = a & b;
```

But I also want to do:

```
if( a && b) {
   //do work
}
```

My inline operator declaration for && is not correct, but I am not sure what to change it to.

Ideas?

Comment: Don't prefix your identifiers with underscores.  It's reserved for the implementation.  Also, what are the semantics you expect for your operator `&&`?  Currently, it will only return `true` if both operands have at least one common bit set.  Only you can tell whether this is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of problems with your code

1. You define `TraceLevel` but use `LogLevel`
2. Your definition of `operator&` is after your use of it in the definition of `operator&&`

I have renamed `LogLevel` to be `TraceLevel` and have moved the definition of `operator&` to be before the definition of `operator&&` (and as suggested in the comment removed underscores), see working example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f2c80a8923d3256).

```
#include <iostream>

enum class TraceLevel : uint32_t {

    // Basic logging levels (may be combined with trace level)
    All = 0xFFFFFFFF,
    None = 0x00000000,
    Info = 0x00000001,
    Warning = 0x00000002,
    Error = 0x00000004,
    Logging = 0x0000000F,
};

inline constexpr TraceLevel
operator&(TraceLevel x, TraceLevel y) {
    return static_cast<TraceLevel>
        (static_cast<uint32_t>(x) & static_cast<uint32_t>(y));
}

inline bool operator&&(TraceLevel x, TraceLevel y) {
    return static_cast<uint32_t>(x & y) > 0;
}

int main() {

    TraceLevel a = TraceLevel::Info;
    TraceLevel b = TraceLevel::Warning;

    TraceLevel c = a & b;

    if( a && b) {
        std::cerr << "a && b is true\n";
    } else {
        std::cerr << "a && b is false\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: On #1, yeah, that was a typo.   I actually had it in my program as `TraceLevel LogLevel = TraceLevel::Warning;`    Got them corn-fused when I retyped.   As far as the order, ah, that makes sense.   However, even changing the order VS2013 still chokes on it.   I get these three errors when I try to put it in the way it works in Coliru:
`error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'TraceLevel'`, 
`error C2433: 'constexpr' : 'inline' not permitted on data declarations` and finally `error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int`

Comment: Doh!!  Nevermind...my bad.   Thanks for the tip on the order!